# PostgreSQL copy to a second column to a NON empty table from csv file

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have very strange problem: I cant COPY from csv file to empty column of non empty table from its beginning.
For example table FOO has two columns N1 and N2.
I have two csv file with different numbers of values.
I copy to first column N1 from first csv file.
Then I need to copy to second column N2 from second csv file.
It copies the data, but not from the fist row of the second column, it starts where first column ends.
I need to copy from the beginning of first and second column.
Now it looks like (select * from foo;):

```
N1    N2
a      -
b      -
c      -
d      -
       a
       b
```

Please explain me how to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to merge both csv files and then import it? COPY is working as it should. It doesn't look for empty values on the table to insert it. Every row in a csv file will be a new registry to the database.

Comment: COPY insert data, it doesn't do updates.

Comment: I know, and specially create new and empty column.
I copy to newly create column. And it is not easy merge, I need to make two columns one from one file and another from second. My knowledge is not enough for this.

Comment: No, you don't. The new column in the same table is the same registry as the first column. So if you have a table with column A and import say 10 rows you will have 10 rows in your table. Then you add an empty column B on your table. You STILL have 10 rows in your table. The COPY command will insert new registries. It will not look for the empty registries from the column B and start from it. As I said, it only do INSERT statements it wont do UPDATES. To solve your problem you either merge those files and import or you import the B file to another table then update the registries on the A table

Comment: Thanks. For me to update table is mach easy than to write script in bash to merge two csv files.